# how to search static internal lib in cmake script

Tags: c++, cmake

project root folder contains cmakelists.txt with common settings and also includes subfolders "app" and "lib". How should I write a script for "app" to link with "lib" output?

current "app" cmakelists is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(app)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} app.c)
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} lib)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME0} lib)
```

last line generates the error that couldn't find this.
I'd like to avoid direct specifying the path to "lib" output, because of it depends of cmake settings, and I've expected that dependency command was successful, then link should be too, no?

Comment: Is `${PROJECT_NAME0}` a typo? Did you mean `${PROJECT_NAME}`?

Comment: What errors do you get? How do the `lib` cmake file look like? How do you "include" it?

Comment: Are both app and lib part of the same project (i.e. should be build within a single cmake/make call) or should they be build separately? (the earlier is a lot easier, the later more difficult and in general involves find_package scripts)

Comment: sorry for my inattention - you are absolutely right PROJECT_NAME0 - is a typo but not here only , in a script too ,tthis fix solved the problem , many thanks

Comment: regarding the structure - yes, both builds within single cmake project, subprojects are included using add_subdirectories

Comment: lib is an unfortunate name.

Comment: you are right, this name in the post only, in real project it sounds like "my-project_lib"